# HDD spindown on 14.04LTS

Tags: hard-drive, spindown

I can't get my drives (SEAGATE 750MB, Western Digital 1TB & Western Digital 500GB) to spindown on 14.04LTS. I have added the following lines on hdparm.conf which worked fine on 12.04LTS

```
command_line {
    hdparm -S 240 /dev/sdb
}

command_line {
    hdparm -S 240 /dev/sdc
}

command_line {
    hdparm -S 240 /dev/sdd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is AHCI enabled in your BIOS? If not then do so and try the hdparm command again. Then it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that for some reason the HDDs aren't going to spin down if the value is 120 or higher.
It works well with a value of 119, id est:

```
sudo hdparm -S 119 /dev/sdX
```

You can check the HDD status with:

```
sudo hdparm -C /dev/sdX
```

Edit: this is on 14.04